# How to handle multiple user running the same loop on Oracle using JDBC through beanshell sampler

Tags: jmeter

Through a beanshell sampler I am running the following loop query on Oracle, now it is running fine with one user but when I am trying to run the same with multiple user it is failing and giving `PK violation` error although after every iteration I am deleting the records which it setting the pointier to initial position for the first user.

**BeanShell Sampler Script:**

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;

ResultSet rs = null;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

Connection conn = DataSourceElement.getConnection("IMPACTConnectionPrerequisitsII");
String Query = "DECLARE \n" 
           + "j number(4) \n"
           + "BEGIN \n"
           + "FOR j in 11 .. 12 LOOP \n"
           + "INSERT INTO FWA_STAGE_TU \n"
           + "(ID,EXT_ID,BATCH_NO,OPERATION,BLOCK_ROLL_UP_LAST_RECORD,LAST_UPDATED_DATE,ERROR_FLAG,TRIAL_NO,TRIAL_ALIAS_CODE, \n"
            + "COUNTRY_CODE,DISPLAY_UNIT_NO,GROUP_NO,TRIAL_UNIT_REFERENCE,PRIMARY_INVESTIGATOR,PRIMARY_CENTRE,OCATION_NO, \n"
            + "PURPOSE_CODE,MANAGING_MED_UNIT_CODE,UPDATING_MED_UNIT_CODE,FINANCE_MED_UNIT_CODE,PATIENTS_ALL_SET_UP_FLAG, \n"
            + "PATIENT_MONITORING_FLAG,COMMENTS,CONFIRMED_FLAG,CONFIRMED_BY,CONFIRMED_DATE,ROLLUP_ROLLDOWN_PLANNED_FIGS, \n"
            + "DOC_COLLECTION_INDICATOR,VALIDATED_PAT_CAP,MAXIMUM_PAT_CAP,PREFERRED_LANGUAGE_CODE,NEW_DISPLAY_UNIT_NO, \n"
            + "TOTAL_OPEN_DCF_ISSUES_NO,ORDER_INTERVAL,ORDER_INTERVAL_UNITS,DATA_SOURCE_CODE,RANK_SEQ) \n"
            + "VALUES (j, 1, 10, 'I', NULL, SYSDATE, 'N', 102922, 'TESTTRIAL4', 'BEL', \n"
           + "j, NULL, 'BELTU'||j, 130262, 124236, NULL, 'PATTR', 'FP', 'FP', 'FP', 'N', 'Y', 'TESTTU'||j, \n"
           + "'Y', 999999, SYSDATE, NULL, 'P', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) \n"
           + "END LOOP \n"
           + "END";

try {
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error message: ", ex);
    throw ex;
}
finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
    }
    if (pstmt != null) {
        pstmt.close();
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
        log.info("!!!! Connection closed to database !!!!");
    }
```

How to get this work for multiple user ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about **multiple users** it might be the situation when one user haven't deleted the inserted data yet and another one is creating the same data.

The solution would be using some unique value as `ID` (or what is the column which has [primary key constraint)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP), if you don't have any better idea you could use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) which returns the number of current thread (virtual user)

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) so it worth considering migration. In your case no code changes will be required at all.